# Troubleshooting an inner join that's not finding expected matches

Tags: sql, sas, inner-join

Okay...I'm not a coder and my code has lots of steps that would make it difficult to post and get an outright answer.  So I am looking for general steps you would follow if an inner join does not seem to be working correctly.  Here is my general situation:

Problem with inner join:
I start with two tables that I basically am appending to each other - they share most fields, including "id".  One of the tables contains households who receive an email, and the other table are households who did not receive an email - "controls".  So I append them into a single table, keep in mind they come from different sources with different processes creating them.

Then I match the id against another table that contains only customers and get a custnum for some of those households that are indeed customers.

Next is to use the custnum variable to join to a sales table.  At least some controls, and likely a greater number of the mailed households should be customers and have sales - the point of the email was to obviously bring about sales.

My problem is that NO control households are showing up with any sales.  That is impossible, given that there are hundreds of thousands of households.  I'm getting a reasonable number of matches to the emailed households.

In trying to troubleshoot this all I can figure is that somehow there is a format issue of the id or the custnum fields between the mailed and control households - perhaps because they did come from different sources and I had to append them together at the start.

Is this possible?  Should both the format and informat be the same for each key?What else could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please post some example code and data ?

Comment: There is no way an `INNER JOIN` is not working correctly - and what does it even mean? It's working the way it's supposed to. There is probably a misunderstanding in the concept on your side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be facetious but please let's get beyond semantics.  It is not working as I intended (or as I expected) due to some unforeseen issue that may be related to the format of the keys I'm using or to something else - which is what I'm asking advice on.

Comment: Hi Renee, I'd recommend finding a few rows in your two input tables which aren't getting matched as you'd like in the join, enter them into two new datasets with cards/data lines (as few columns as possible, maybe just one non-key column from each), then perform your join. If you still don't understand the results, you'll have a clear, minimal reproducible example that I'm sure someone here will be able to solve for you quickly.

Comment: If there was an error in types there would be a note in the log. I'm assuming you have a clean log?  If not, post the error. Also, check the variable that you're matching on - do it manually. Pick 10 from table 1 and look them up in table 2. See if there's matches, and check that the types and format match.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to append data using a `DATA STEP` than using SQL statements.

```
data both ;
  set email noemail;
run;
```

If you want to do the same thing in SQL then use `UNION` instead of any type of join.

```
proc sql ;
  create table both as
     select * from email
     union
     select * from noemail
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful.  If I use a datastep and the key variable (even though I'm not actually using it as a key here) has a different format in each file will there be two fields in the new table, even though they have the same name?

Comment: No there will be one field (if they both have the same name), but note it will have the length and format as defined in the FIRST dataset in the set statement (so could potentially truncate if the second dataset has a longer length).